# I have two sets that form a function

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

So I have x =(0,1,2,3,...) and y= (-1,-2,-3,...)

Where x=0 then y=-1

etc.

How do I find the function formula for this ? Any hints would be good.
Thank you !

Comment: Hint:  it is linear.  i.e. $f(x)=Ax+B$ for suitable constants $A,B$.

Comment: Not easy to restrict to a hint in this case.

Comment: Ok, thanks lulu, I was able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

$\begin{array}{cc}
x & y\\
0 & -1\\
1 & -2\\
2 & -3\\
3 & -4\\
4 & -5\\
5 & -6\end{array}$

Answer (score 0):

let function$f$  as  $f(x)=-x-1$.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to find,

$$y=f(x)=-(x+1)$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Plot some of the points from $X$ and $Y$ on the plane. Then connect a line through these points. If you find that you can connect the points with a straight line then your function will be linear, ie of the form $y = mx + b$ where $m$ is the slope of the line and $b$ is the y-intercept. These quantities should be easy enough to find.

Answer (score 0):

One can see the answer f(x)=-(x+1). For the general case, look up the word " polynomial interpolation".